# How to find the difference between two String ArrayList using java 8 Streams?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections, java-8

I need to find the difference between the two string Array list using java 8 features .
Current i am doing it like this

```
final List<String> a = new ArrayList<>();
        a.add("1");
        a.add("2");
        a.add("3");

        final List<String> b = new ArrayList<>();
        b.add("1");
        b.add("2");
        b.add("4");

        final List<String> result = a.stream().filter((s) -> b.stream().noneMatch(s::equals))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        final List<String> result2 = b.stream().filter((s) -> a.stream().noneMatch(s::equals))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println(result2);

        final List<String> FinalResult = java.util.stream.Stream.concat(result.stream(), result2.stream())
                .distinct()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());   

        System.out.println(FinalResult);
```

Can any one suggest a cleaner and shorter code for the same thing ? I am  feeling it can be done in some other simpler way .

Comment: is repetition of an element in the collection allowed?

Comment: You can do something like `Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).filter(s -> a.contains(s) != b.contains(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @TalOhana thank you this helped as well

Comment: @TalOhana is it asking m to make a and  b inside filter as final . why is it required ? i am not willing to make it final

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same thing using below code:

```
List<String> result = b.stream()
                       .filter(not(new HashSet<>(a)::contains))
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());

private static <T> Predicate<T> not(Predicate<T> predicate) {
    return predicate.negate();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: this is awesome ! thank you

Comment: your above code only gives elements of list b and that are not in A i.e B-A . but i need A-B + B-A elements